# RSS Feed won't work: something wrong with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I've been writing a simple PHP script which is supposed to generate a RSS Feed extracting data from a MySQL database.

```
<?php
require("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]mysql.php");
$type = $_GET["type"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Setting WHERE Type = \"$type\"");
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo "
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>
<rss version=\"2.0\">
  <channel>
    <title>Vhannibal &ndash; I migliori setting per Dreambox! &ndash; Feed RSS</title>
    <link>http://www.vhannibal.net/</link>
    <description>".$type."</description>
";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "
    <item>
      <title>$row[Name]</title>
      <link>http://www.vhannibal.net/download_setting.php?id=$row[ID]</link>
      <description>".strftime("%e %b", $row["Date"])."</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
";
}
?>
```

The problem is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` comes after an unwanted empty line generated by the PHP script which I think is the reason why it doesn't work. Am I right? How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the database character encoding?

Comment: I tried utf-8 too, nothing changed.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the newline before <?xml version ..?

Comment: Your echo command appears to be generating a newline before the <xml... tag.  Is that the newline you want to get rid of?

Comment: I can't, the PHP script adds it. That's why I asked how to remove it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to ob_clean(); too but the line was still there.

Comment: Er, why doesn't your echo command start:  echo "<xml ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `&ndash;` entity in the title element which is not valid in xml (it's an html defined entity); just use "-" or use the decimal version: `&#8210;`.

Also, you need to put the `channel` and `rss` end tags outside of the while cycle.

To get rid of the first blank line, just replace

```
   echo "
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    [...]
```

with

```
   echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
   [...]
```

Comment: what's the problem? you may have other html entities inside your item - title tag

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> line. I read the empty line caused by the PHP script could cause this. I tried to ob_clean(); too. Nothing changed.

Comment: I updated the answer to get rid of the first blank line, but if you don't fix the problems with entities and close tags as above you wont get a valid xml